# How to access entity from EntityReferenceItem?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

I have the attached array below and need help figuring out how to access the 'entity' attribute that is under the protected "properties" array (see screenshot).

I am using the [Viewfield module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj54oS92Y3YAhUDLmMKHSKzA2wQFggsMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fviewfield&usg=AOvVaw0bNeYA5rY7MqzhFqg_zecW)

[image: Entity Reference - Entity value]

background:
field_name is an entity reference field. I need to get the EntityReference so that I can call getTarget() to get the EntityAdapter and then call EntityAdapter->getValue().

I have tried the following but they all give errors. The idea is to get the EntityReference which is the 'entity' value. How can i do this?

```
mytheme_preprocess_viewfield_item(&vars) {

  $element = $vars['element'];
  $results = $element['#content']['#view']->result;

  foreach($results as $row) {
    $entity = $row->_entity
    $offset = $entity->get('field_name')->offsetGet(0)

kint($entity->get($video_field_name)) /* result of screenshot */

    $entityReference = $offset->get('entity') /* failed */
    $entityReference = $offset->getProperties() /* failed */
    $entityReference = $offset->getEntity() /* failed */
    $entityReference = $offset->getValue() /* failed */
  }//end foreach
}//end theme_preprocesss
```

The error message is: replace getValue() with any of the above

Call to a member function getValue() on null

Comment: It would greatly help to give specific code how you got the array.

Comment: @GiorgosK i have updated the question. Additionally i added the kint() statement that generates the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `entity` in the foreach loop is not empty you should be able to do

```
$entity->field_name->entity
//or perhaps
$entity->field_name->referencedEntities();
```

Comment: the first version worked for me. I still testing the refencedEntities and if it fails I can provide an update otherwise both seem to work. I have added additional validation to ensure entity is not empty

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an EntityReferenceItem you can get the entity with `getEntity()`

```
$item->getEntity();
```

And if you have an EntityReferenceItemList:

```
$list = $itemList->get(field_name);
foreach ($list as $item) {
  $entity = $item->getEntity();
}
// or
$itemList->get(field_name)->referencedEntities();
```